# Inheritance (or other way to re-use) for a simple functionality

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a class that in order to control how to create instances and to ensure unique values, I did in Class the following:

1. limited the constructor to private lavel,
2. creating a static dictionary for existing instances
3. a static function that returns by key an exsiting or new item from the dictionary.

here example:

```
class Foo
{
    private Foo() { }

    private static Dictionary<string, Foo> FooCollection = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();

    public static Foo GetFoo(string key)
    {
        Foo result;
        if (FooCollection.TryGetValue(key, out result) == false)
        {
            result = new Foo();
            FooCollection.Add(key, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I now have a few more classes with the same principle exactly. Inheritance is not possible here that all classes will share the same Dictionary.

So there is a way to reuse code?

Comment: Very important: Inheritance is *not* a means of code reuse! Inheritance models an `is a kind of` relationship. If it just so happens to reuse some code, that's a side-effect, not the intent. To reuse code, you probably want a `has a` relationship, accomplished through *composition*.

Comment: Just to add on, it is not necessary that the other classes are going to use the type Foo to be added to the dictionary. They may use different types. In that case, it will fail anyways. The solution is provided below by D Stanley.

Answer (score 6):

Based on what you posted, you can make it generic:

```
class Factory<T> where T:new()
{
    private Factory() { }

    private static Dictionary<string, T> Inventory = new Dictionary<string, T>();

    public static T GetObject(string key)
    {
        T result;
        if (Inventory.TryGetValue(key, out result) == false)
        {
            result = new T();
            Inventory.Add(key, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that I called the class a `Factory` since it's using the [Flyweight Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Comment: Does every type of `T` get its own dictionary here? Because if not it would fail with to equal keys for different types...

Comment: No, it won't fail - each type has it's own _Factory_ which has it's own dictionary.

Comment: You are right - I wasn't sure about that behaviour with generics, but I tested it and it works great => your solution is the way to go...

Comment: Yes - with generics you get a separate class for each type (or set of types)

Comment: @DStanley, Thanks, Your solution is great! But ... problem, it requires me to allow a public constructor in the derived class, so how do I limit the uncontrolled instances creating

Comment: You need a constructor for the factory to create instances.  If the types are in the same _assembly_ you can make the constructors `internal`.

Comment: @DStanley the `where T : new()` Does not allow `internal`, its require `public`!

Comment: OK see that now.  The factory needs _some_ way to create new types, what is the concern if types are created outside the factory?